# Sorting an ArrayList using another ArrayList field for a Custom Object

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-8

I have 2 arraylists, RequestList and ResponseList of a custom object.
The request list has 10 soap requests with RequestHeader and RequestBody.
10 is an example (could be even 1000 or more or even 1 million records)
Now, RequestHeader(Header.java) has an element called RequestId of type String

Request Object

```
<CustomClassRequest>
 <header>
    <RequestId>1</RequestId>
 </header>
 <Body></Body>
</CustomClassRequest>
```

Assume the RequestList has 10 soap requests with requestId starting from 1 to 10 
(using numbers for simplification of this usecase)

Now, I trigger these soap requests in parallel and loose the insertion orders 
when I receive my response as it was in my RequestList.
Hence, my ResponseList will have the response of all those 10 soap requests 
but in different order of the requestId.

Response Object

```
<CustomClassResponse>
 <header>
    <RequestId>1</RequestId>
 </header>
 <Body></Body>
</CustomClassResponse>
```

Note: The header in the Response is of a different class ResponseHeader.java

Can I achieve sorting my ResponseList using the common field RequestId 
based on the insertion order how the RequestList exists.

Let me know if Java 8 API has possible solution or even using any third party solution

Comment: I assume that request Id is not sorted then in the request list otherwise you could sort the response list independently. I think you would need to loop over the request list, find the corresponding response and add it to a new ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can use java8 lambda expression

e.g.

```
resposneList.stream()
   .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getHeader().getRequestId()
   .compareTo(o2.getHeader().getRequestId()))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a Comparator as you don't compare elements of the list between them to compute their order.
You could create a Map from the response List that associated id to response.
Then stream the request and map its id to the map key.
Here is solution that creates a new List for response :

```
Map<Integer, Response> responseByIdMap = responses.stream()
                                                  .collect(toMap(Response::getId, r->r);

responses = 
request.stream()
       .map( req -> responseByIdMap.get(req.getId))
       .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Let me try this approach.